# EJB injection not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, netbeans-7

I have 2 EJB module projects and I want from one of the projects to call a stateless no-interface bean from another project. I want to inject the bean to be called using the EJB annotation. The problem is the injection doesn't work(I use NetBeans 7.4 if that is relevant).

The stateless no-interface EJB being called:

```
package standalonepackage;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;


@Stateless
@LocalBean

public class StandaloneBean {

     private static final String message="Greetings!";

     public String returnMessage(){
          return message;
     }
}
```

The interface of the bean that calls the bean above(this ejb resides in another ejb module project)

```
@Local
public interface ExampleBeanLocal {

     public String getMessage();
}
```

The implementation of the interface:

```
@Stateless
public class ExampleBean implements ExampleBeanLocal {

    @EJB
    private StandaloneBean standaloneBean;

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return String.format("Me - and the second message %s",  standaloneBean.returnMessage());
    }

}
```

I also have a main class that just calls the ExampleBean getMessage method(MainClass is located in the second ejb module project):

```
public class MainClass {


    private static ExampleBeanLocal instance = new ExampleBean();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(instance.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you think that dependency injection is going to happen when running this code as a regular client application?

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this- isn't there any way I could make it work from a client application?

Comment: Of course not, you need a JEE container to have JEE features available to you :/

Comment: It's JavaEE not JEE, I keep seeing this always, no offence!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all if you want to access your business logic as EJB then first you will need to deploy the EJB in an application server. During the deployment process the application server will create something called the JNDI name which is like a gatepass to access your business logic.

Secondly, there are two ways you can invoke an EJB.
 1. Creating ContextLookup using JNDI name
 2. Using Context Dependency Injection CDI (only within the same Container)

You cannot invoke an EJB using CDI from a POJO ( since it is not contained in any container and the EJB your accessing is in a different JVM ). If you want to access an EJB from a POJO you'll need to use @Remote and use the ContextLookup way of accessing an EJB, you can find more information here
http://wiki.netbeans.org/CreatingEJB3UsingNetbeansAndGlassfish

Answer (score 2):

You need application server with EJB container to run this. Have a look at JBoss, Apache TomEE or something else.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way to run your jar GLASFISH_HOME/bin/appclient -client app.jar

before compiling your maven project mvn assembly:assembly

and add your main class in your pom.xml